# What to do with error 1004 in loop through column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use this code for showing the overflow to another value in the column `I` in sheet `20170224-SUAGDB`. But I'm getting an `Error 1004` about the line `If Works....Value Then`. Can somebody help me with the error?

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    If Worksheets("20170224-SUAGDB").Cells(i, 9).Value <> Worksheets("20170224-SUAGDB").Cells((i + 1), 9).Value Then
        Cells(i, 9).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Are you getting that error before the loop even runs once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your objects are not fully qualified. For instance, get the last row number  in column "I" (9) in  `Worksheets("20170224-SUAGDB").

Try the code below:

```
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("20170224-SUAGDB")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row in column "I" (column 9)
        If .Cells(i, 9).Value <> .Cells((i + 1), 9).Value Then
            .Cells(i, 9).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Setting the cell color on the current worksheet based on values from other worksheets might have been intended. Except for that line, all the other objects do seem to be fully qualified. Anyway I don't think it can cause this error. Referencing a row number greater than the total rows as per @dot.Py's answer can; I think that's actually the issue.

Comment: @SantiBailors I think it's more likely the PO meant to look at the smae workbook. If you get the last occupied row number, you won't face this error at all.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is off-track, it should not be marked as accepted. Regardless of whether the code in it works (and I don't think it does if the last available row is not empty), the reason that it states for the error is just wrong. Objects not being fully qualified has nothing to do with the error. The reason for the error is the one mentioned in dot.Py's answer, and also the related solution, which as stated by the OP works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't `.select'ed` any specific `Range()` in your `Worksheet`, your `Rows.Count` value is equal to `1048576`.

You can check it's value using `MsgBox Rows.Count`.

So, when your loop goes from `1` to `1048576`, in the last iteration when you try to compare `.Cells(i, 9).Value` with `.Cells((i + 1), 9).Value`, the second term "explodes" your total number of rows!

Your code looks for the row number `1048577` - which don't exists - so it throws a `1004` error.

One possible solutions is changing :

- This: `For i = 2 To Rows.Count`
- To this: `For i = 2 To Rows.Count - 1`

This solution will loop through `all - 1` rows even if they don't contain any data.

Or maybe even:

- This: `For i = 2 To Rows.Count`
- To this: `For i = 2 To Range("I:I").End(xlDown).Row - 1`

This solution get the last non-blank row value of the selected column.

**ps.** If you don't add `- 1` in `For i = 2 To Range("I:I").End(xlDown).Row - 1`, and your worksheet contains some data at the row number `1048576`, your code will throw the same error 1004.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the actual number of rows is 165000. So the loop takes a while and than after the loop the error pops up.

Comment: You have `165000`rows filled with data, so the code `Rows.Count` will return `1048576` and the code `Range("I:I").End(xlDown).Row` will return `165000`. Test it using the second approach and you'll see there's a difference in execution time. Btw, have you tested the code with `-1`?

Comment: Yes the -1 works much better. I actually want to paste the found values (which are now been made red) in a new sheet. But the code explodes again..